# Dealing with the inverted Y axis while graphing in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am using Javascripts built in canvas feature to draw a graph showing home loan payments, loan balance, and equity based on user input. I am not able to use any other form of graphing package, as the code is part of an assessment.

My graph is drawn by converting data to X and Y coordinates. When a loan price is input, some home loan payment equations calculate the total amount payed, which is divided by the canvas width to get a spacing variable. This spacing variable is used to convert dollar amounts into pixels on the canvas. A similar setup is used to get the years and months spacing pixels.

The problem I am having is that the Y axis on Javascript's canvas is inverted, with 0 being the top of the canvas and 280, my canvas height, being at the bottom. So far, I have been able to work around this, simply by swapping "+" and "-" operators, however, I am currently creating the code that draws the Loan Balance line on the graph, and the inversion is causing issues that I can't seem to solve. It may be something simple that I'm just not seeing, or it may be a more complex problem that needs to be solved, but either way, I can't figure it out.

```
X = 0; // same as before, iterators both set back to 0 for the new line.
            iterator = 0;
            c.beginPath // this next line is for loan balance, it starts at 300000 and goes down with each payment made, then back up with each bit of interest accrued.
            // due to the fact that the y axis begins at the top, this means that the pixels for payments is added to the pixel count, and the interest accrued is taken away.
            c.moveTo(0, loanLocation) // set starting point to x=0 y= loanLocation
            while (X <= 510)// loan balance loop
            {
                X = X + 0.001; // iterates X by .001 each time, allowing an accurate subpixel resolution loop, see above for why this is needed.
                iterator = iterator + 0.001;
                if (iterator >= monthSpacing)
                {
                    loanBalance = loanBalance - monthlyPayment + (monthlyInterest * loanBalance);
                    //alert(loanBalance);
                    //interestY = 
                    //alert(interestY);
                    //alert(X + " " + monthSpacing);
                    loanY = loanY + paymentY - (loanY * monthlyInterest);
                    //alert(loanY);
                    //loanY = loanBalance * paySpacing;
                    c.lineTo(X, loanY);
                    iterator = 0;
                }
            }
            c.strokeStyle = "black"
            c.stroke(); // there is no fill for this line, so it is just left as a stroke.
```

This is the set of code which draws the line, above it are a few variables which are being used here:

```
var X = 0;
var iterator = 0;
var monthSpacing = yearSpacing / 12;
//alert(yearSpacing);
//alert(monthSpacing);
var monthlyInterest = interest/1200; // this gives the montly interest rate, the monthly interest pixel amount is below
//alert(monthlyInterest);//debugging, comment out.
var paymentY = monthlyPayment * paySpacing;
var interestY = monthlyInterest * paySpacing; // this is inaccurate, the interestY needs to be gotten by multiplying the remaining loan balance by the 
//monthly interest each month.
//var interestY; // will be used further down, must be calculated monthly so cannot be set outside of the line drawing loops.
var totalY = 280;
var equityY = 280;
var loanBalance = loan;
var loanY = loanLocation;
```

When run I get a strange inversion of the desired outcome, I want the loan balance line to curve down towards zero, but instead, the curve is happening in the opposite direction, I have tried two different ways to get the coordinates, the loanBalance way, which involved working with dollar values and converting that to pixels, and the loanY way, which involved working with pixel values directly.

loanBalance provided a line which was the exact inverse of the desired line, it began at the loan value, and curved upwards in the exact opposite direction to what I want, I am confident that the math I'm using for the loanBalance method is accurate, I simply cannot think of a way to convert that dollar value into pixels due to the inverted nature of the Y axis.

loanY provides a line which is headed "down", but is curving downwards at an increasingly shortened rate, this leads me to believe that while the subtraction (addition due to the inversion) of monthly repayments is accurately being calculated, the addition (subtraction) of monthly interest is being calculated incorrectly. Multiplication cannot be simply replaced with division like addition and subtraction can, so converting this value to pixels is proving difficult. The line drawn by the loanY way is definitely being affected by the inversion, but is not a perfect inverse of the desired line, the math being used for that way is clearly very wrong.

Ideally, I'd like to find a way to use the loanY way, it is consistent with the rest of the program, and can be used when not working with such obvious values as dollars. If I have to though, I will use the loanBalance way.

If you aren't entirely certain what I'm asking, or what the code being used is, I can post the program in it's entirety if that would help. I've not done that yet as I don't want to clutter the question more than I already have.

Comment: don't take the comments in the code as gospel, some of those are inaccurate, some are blatantly wrong. I comment as I type to remember my ideas and theories, for example, the comment that says that interestY is inaccurate is, ironically blatantly wrong, I was attempting to figure something out and wrote that while using that variable for something else, it's still there until I've figured out what to do.

Comment: No luck yet, but I have managed to get both variations to give me the same perfect inverse of the desired line, beginning at the loanValue and curving in the opposite direction, it seems the discrepency was the attempt at "subtracting" the interest percentage, I'm sure I learnt how to invert a multiplication in high school, but that was so long ago now that I can't even begin to think of what it might have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change to a Cartesian coordinate system like this:

```
// get a reference to your canvas element (eg it might have id='myCanvas')
var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');

// get the context for the canvas
var context=canvas.getContext('2d');

// vertically flip the canvas so its Y origin is at the bottom
context.setTransform(1,0,0,-1,0,canvas.height);
```

This makes y==0 at the bottom of the canvas and increases upward.

If you're using other transformations, then put this transformation before the others.

Comment: Must I do this at the start of the program, or can I do this at any point? This would make things much easier, but I'd like to avoid having to go through and un-invert everything else to fix the one thing that I can't invert properly.

Comment: Use it as needed. If that's only for 1 chart then do it before the chart and then reset the default state with `context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`. Cheers!

Comment: That's done it, thanks. Would you be able to rephrase your answer to make it slightly clearer for new users, specifically canvasElementHeight? Perhaps include the html that defines a canvas called "myCanvas" and then use "myCanvas.height"? I was able to look it up and work out what syntax to use but I know for a fact that some of my classmates wouldn't.

Comment: Sure...be glad to! :-)

Comment: Thanks a ton Mark. I had some other issues afterwords caused by the same inversion problem, my loanLocation coordinate was inverted, which meant the marker which showed the initial loan price was inverted too. It took me a while, but I finally figured it out. If I hadn't used your advice, I don't think I'd have been able to figure out why it was wrong.